# Count Unique values on an array based on multile criteria google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet where in TAB A I have a database with the "raw" data imported from another db, where I have some products with unique ID's and a few other columns.

What I'm trying to do is on TAB B, using an arrayformula, is count all of the unique numbers for the specific ID, I left an example on TAB B on the top rows using QUERY formula.

here is the spreadsheet link if you wanna take a look at the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-pFeQWVD_0fpBdC-GzHBlnr92bGDQn-6kqEdWfTAkPI/edit#gid=487890997

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this QUERY for selecting the UNIQUE values of ID and Product number in B1:

```
=QUERY(QUERY('TAB A'!A:C;"SELECT A,C,COUNT(B) WHERE A is not null group by A,C");"Select Col1,Col2")
```

And this MAKEARRAY in D2 for the counts of unique values:

```
=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(B2:B);COUNTA(D1:1);LAMBDA(r;c;COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(INDEX('TAB A'!D2:F;;c);'TAB A'!A2:A=INDEX(B2:B;r))))))
```

[image]